# Synonym Graph is not giving accurate results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-synonym

I am trying to implement Multi-Word Synonyms

This is the index setting

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms": [
            "roti making machine, bread making machine => chapati making machine",
            "chapati making machine => phulka making machine",
            "bread machine, bread pressing machine => bread making machine"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are the sample documents

```
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Roti Making Machine"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Bread Pressing Machine"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Chapati Making Machine"}
```

When I search for "Roti Making Machine", I get this

Search Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Roti Making Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Results:

```
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.2478919,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "product",
                "_id": "UJcRBYwBN6t5MCbzznDr",
                "_score": 1.2478919,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Roti Making Machine"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "product",
                "_id": "UZcRBYwBN6t5MCbzznDr",
                "_score": 0.26706278,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Bread Pressing Machine"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "product",
                "_id": "UpcRBYwBN6t5MCbzznDr",
                "_score": 0.26706278,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Chapati Making Machine"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Ideally, the first result that I should get is "Chapati Making Machine", because it is the synonym of the searched term. Can anyone please help me identify what is the issue?